# Whats the difference between DataTables widget and Tables Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Im going to create an excel like application in Flutter where the user can input a quantity to one of the cells and the app automatically calculate its values based on quantity.

Shall i use DataTables or Tables widget?

Comment: The `DataTable` would be a better option for an excel like application. A `DataTable` pretty much acts like an excel file by letting you sort and edit the data inside it while a `Table` doesn't allow that.

Comment: Umm are you sure? As far as i know, you cant edit the data inside a DataTable. If so, how?

And you can easily add a TextField widget inside a table

Comment: You can edit data in a DataTable by adding and icon on the side and changing the text. You could also do it in a Table but it is harder to do it there. Overall, DataTable is meant to act like an excel file while Table doesn't. You could still configure Table to look like DataTable but it would be easier to just use DataTable instead.

Answer (score 18):

Both accept widgets as cell content like TextField, Slider or just Text. Anywhere there are some differences:

| Feature | Table | DataTable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Checkbox column | no | showCheckBoxColumn |
| Set column width | columnWidth | no |
| Set row height | no | dataRowHeight |
| Sortable | no | integrated |

If a cell with a *no* this does not mean, its not possible. The feature is just
not directly supported by the widget. In all cases sizes will computed according to Flutters rendering engine: constraints go down, sizes go up.

Anybody please feel free to add more content to above comparison.